# Guice Dependency Injection over method, first steps

Tags: dependency-injection, guice

Im using Java 1.6 with guice 3.0 and im trying to get Dependency Injection working.
I want to switch from Manual Dependency Injection to guice.

Heres My class wehere i want to use the dependency:

```
public class QSManager implements IQSManager {
    private IPdfManager pdfManager;
    @Inject
    public void setPdfManager(IPdfManager pdfManager){
        this.pdfManager = pdfManager;
    }
```

And Heres My Manager Module

```
public class PdfManagerModule implements Module {

    @Override
    public void configure(Binder binder) {
         binder.bind(IPdfManager.class).to(PdfManager.class).in(Singleton.class);
    }
}
```

And my desired Dependency:

```
@Singleton
public class PdfManager implements IPdfManager {
```

But if i run it, it never injects a dependency. As example:

1. i create the Main app: QSManager manager = new QSManager(params);
2. i try the injection: manager.test() where test is a System.out.println(pdfManager); which returns null

Can anyone point me in the right direction or show me the error? Thank you!

Comment: One tipp when you are new to DI: never use "new" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind that interface in your configuration with:

```java
bind(IQSManager.class).to(QSManager.class);
```

and use Guice to create your `QSManager` instead of using `new`:

```java
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new PdfManagerModule());
IQSManager manager = injector.getInstance(IQSManager.class);
manager.test();
```

Comment: even if i want to inject the PdfManager into my QSManager?

Comment: Yes. `Guice` injects the dependencies for QSManager when it creates that instance. If you just use `new` this bypasses Guice. Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: @MemLeak, not even, but *because* you want it. If you want dependency injection to work, you *have* to use DI container everywhere you want a new instance. After all, how should Guice know that you want to inject something if you won't tell it?

Comment: true sorry, it was a logical problem ith my thinking. at the google io presentation they say: DI with setters happens after the constructor is invoked. But how should guice know when the ctr is invoked. Thank you guys!